# Draw Ring with shapeRenderer in LibGDX

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shapes

I want to draw a ring (circle with big border) with the shaperenderer.

I tried two different solutions:

1. Solution: draw n-circles, each with 1 pixel width and 1 pixel bigger than the one before. Problem with that: it produces a graphic glitch. (also with different Multisample Anti-Aliasing values)
2. Solution: draw one big filled circle and then draw a smaller one with the backgroundcolor. Problem: I can't realize overlapping ring shapes. Everything else works fine.

[image: Problems with the solutions]

I can't use a ring texture, because I have to increase/decrease the ring radius dynamic. The border-width should always have the same value.

How can I draw smooth rings with the shaperenderer?

EDIT:
Increasing the line-width doesn't help:
[image: big width = also problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeshBuilder` has the option to create a ring using the `ellipse` method. It allows you to specify the inner and outer size of the ring. Normally this would result in a Mesh, which you would need to render yourself. But because of a recent change it is also possible to use in conjunction with `PolygonSpriteBatch` (an implementation of `Batch` that allows more flexible shapes, while `SpriteBatch` only allows quads). You can use `PolygonSpriteBatch` instead of where you normally would use a `SpriteBatch` (e.g. for your `Stage` or `Sprite` class).

Here is an example how to use it: https://gist.github.com/xoppa/2978633678fa1c19cc47, but keep in mind that you do need the latest nightly (or at least release 1.6.4) for this.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. I tried your example but just get a black screen with the two buttons. I am working with libgdx 1.7.0. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Runs fine for me (I'm on latest nightly), see http://i.imgur.com/s7iQc6x.png. Perhaps create a new project using the setup utility and make sure to copy paste the code exactly as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try making a ring some other way, such as using triangles. I'm not familiar with LibGDX, so here's some
pseudocode.

```
 // number of sectors in the ring, you may need
 // to adapt this value based on the desired size of
 // the ring
int sectors=32;
float outer=0.8; // distance to outer edge
float inner=1.2; // distance to inner edge
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
glNormal3f(0,0,1)
for(int i=0;i<sectors;i++){
 // define each section of the ring 
 float angle=(i/sectors)*Math.PI*2
 float nextangle=((i+1)/sectors)*Math.PI*2
 float s=Math.sin(angle)
 float c=Math.cos(angle)
 float sn=Math.sin(nextangle)
 float cn=Math.cos(nextangle)
 glVertex3f(inner*c,inner*s,0)
 glVertex3f(outer*cn,outer*sn,0)
 glVertex3f(outer*c,outer*s,0)

 glVertex3f(inner*c,inner*s,0)
 glVertex3f(inner*cn,inner*sn,0)
 glVertex3f(outer*cn,outer*sn,0)
}
glEnd()
```

Alternatively, divide the ring into four polygons, each of which consists of one quarter of the whole ring. Then use ShapeRenderer to fill each of these polygons.

Here's an illustration of how you would divide the ring:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question,
maybe, using `glLineWidth();` help you.

example pseudo code:

```
size = 5;

Gdx.gl.glLineWidth(size);

mShapeRenderer.begin(....);
..//
mShapeRenderer.end();
```

Comment: Increasing the line-width doesn't help (see my edited post with picture). I also read, that not every GL-driver supports the lineWidth...