# How to draw a ring with a thick line width in libgdx?

Tags: opengl, libgdx, geometry, shapes

I am using ShapeRenderer to draw a non-filled circle of a certain line width.

I'm trying to do the same thing as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186614/draw-ring-with-shaperenderer-in-libgdx), but it never got a valid answer.

I have tried several solutions :

- increasing line width with `Gdx.gl.glLineWidth()` : a bug causes angles to appear on the ring, because the circle is actually made of several segments (see other question for illustration)
- drawing two circles one onto another, and rotate the second one of 45 degrees to hide these angles, but that doesn't suit me because my circle has an alpha
- drawing one filled circle then another smaller filled circle on top to make the first one look non-filled. This doesn't suit me as I need the inside of the circle to display things under the actor which has an alpha (see other question for illustration)

  ```
  shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
  shapeRenderer.circle(0, 0, radius + lineWidth);
  //sub arc to hide unwanted colour
  shapeRenderer.circle(0, 0, radius);
  shapeRenderer.end();
  ```
- drawing lots of circles of line width 1, increasing the radius by 1 each time, but it's not smooth (see other question for illustration)

  ```
  for (float i = 0; i < lineWidth; i++) {
      shapeRenderer.circle(0, 0, radius + i);
  }
  ```
- drawing lots of arcs of specified line width, to make a circle in the end, but it's not smooth

Comment: Does this help? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110816/shaperenderer-circle-line-width

Comment: @AndrewCheong Nah drawing circles with a thick line width using Gdx.gl.glLineWidth() is buggy, the circle is not smooth

Comment: can you just draw a pre-rendered sprite and be done with it?

Comment: That will work for drawing a circle, but on top of that I also need to draw an arc to make a circular timer like [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ft6s9.png). I can use a sprite for every state of the timer but that's not optimal